# getting undefined with module pattern in javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
var Module = (function() {
    var privateMethod = function() {
        console.log('Private method');
    }
    
    return {
        publicmethod1: function() { console.log('first'); },
        publicmethod2: function() { console.log('second'); }
    }
})();

console.log(Module.publicmethod1());
console.log(Module.publicmethod2());
```

Completely contrary to my expectation ,i am getting

```
first
undefined
second
undefined
```

.
What i was expecting is first and then second but not undefined .What is the reason for this undefined ?

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
console.log(Module.publicmethod1());
console.log(Module.publicmethod2());
```

with

```
Module.publicmethod1();
Module.publicmethod2();
```

Your public methods already have console.log().

To expand...

The statement `Module.publicmethod1()` is not returning anything (which means it returns `undefined`, so when you put that statement in a `console.log()` call, you're printing the result of that method which is `undefined`.

Since you are also calling `console.log()` in your methods, you don't need to print the result of the methods (since they don't return anything anyway).

Answer (score 0):

When you run `publicmethod1()` and `publicmethod2()`, they already log `first` and `second` but they don't return anything. So the last `console.log` calls will log the return value of the called methods, which is `undefined`. Just call

```
Module.publicmethod1();
Module.publicmethod2();
```

and then you don't get any `undefined`.